# Cannot customize the footer of the classicthesis package

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis

I am using the [classicthesis](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis) package as a template for my document. It adds a footer to the document when it is in *draft* mode. The footer is configured in `classicthesis.sty` by the following lines.

```
% ********************************************************************
% Drafting Stuff
% ********************************************************************
\RequirePackage{scrtime} % time access
\newcommand{\finalVersionString}{\relax}
\providecommand{\myVersion}{$\!\!$} % w/o classicthesis-config.tex
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@drafting}}{%      
%    \RequirePackage{draftwatermark}%
%       \SetWatermarkLightness{0.9}
%           \SetWatermarkScale{.5}
%           \SetWatermarkText{\today\ at \thistime}
        \PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{prelim2e}
        \RequirePackage{prelim2e}
        \renewcommand{\PrelimWords}{\relax}
        \renewcommand{\PrelimText}{\footnotesize[\,\today\ at \thistime\ -- \texttt{classicthesis}~\myVersion\,]}
}{\renewcommand{\finalVersionString}{\emph{Final Version} as of \today\ (\texttt{classicthesis}~\myVersion).}}
```

I downloaded the archive available on the website and created a new project for testing purposes. The output is displayed as expected. The footer can also be modified in the *classicthesis* project when I edit the above lines in `classicthesis.sty`.

> [ September 14, 2012 at 13:03 – classicthesis version 4.1 ]

### The problem

My real project is based on version 4.0 (2011/12/17) of the package and includes several custom changes. The file `classicthesis.sty`, however, does not have any changes relevant to the problem. I checked it against the same file of version 4.1 using [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/). All changes in the file refer to the version update.

Somehow I messed up the project. My document shows the footer. But whatever I do to the last two lines of the above source code, **the footer does not change** at all! I can even delete the commands relevant to the footer content as in the following example. It stays the same.

```
...
        \renewcommand{\PrelimWords}{\relax}
        \renewcommand{\PrelimText}{}
}{\renewcommand{\finalVersionString}{}}
```

The only thing that works reliable in my document is that I can remove the `drafting` option from the package to disable the footer. The option can be configured in `classicthesis-config.tex`.

I noticed that I can at least change the version string. I is definied in `classicthesis-config.tex` which contains the following macro.

```
\newcommand{\myVersion}{version 1.0\xspace}
```

I did not prepare a MWE since the total number of files would mess up the whole question. I hope you can still try to help me. Please let me know if I should add more information.
I wonder what could be misconfigured so that the described behavior is possible. Where does the footer information in my project come from? Where can I change the footer definition?

Comment: It seems like you modified the .sty file directly, which is never a good idea. What changes do you want to do to the footer? What information do you want the footer to show?

Comment: Good advice. I checked the file. It should be fine. See my edit. I thought about changing the string "classicthesis" to the title of the document.

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine appropriately `\PrelimText` and `\finalVersionString` in the preamble of your document; here's such a redefinition showing how to replace the defualt "classicthesis" string with the title provided by the `\title` command:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[drafting]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[bmargin=6cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{The Title of This Work}
\author{The Author}

\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@drafting}}
{\renewcommand\myVersion{version 1.0\xspace}
  \renewcommand{\PrelimText}{%
  \footnotesize[\,\today\ at \thistime\ -- \texttt{\@title}~\myVersion\,]}
  \renewcommand{\finalVersionString}{\emph{Final Version} as of \today\ (\texttt{\@title}~\myVersion).}
}
{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Here's an excerpt of the resulting document showing the footer:

[image]

Old versions of `classicthesis` don't define `\myVersion`, so the line

```
\renewcommand\myVersion{...}
```

will have to be changed to

```
\newcommand\myVersion{...}
```

Comment: That works well, but needs an adjustment for the new version of `classicthesis` (4.2). It looks like `\title{}` is no longer used, so `\@title` should probably be replaced with `\myTitle`. (I prefer `\jobname.pdf` for a draft footer.) Also, I comment out `\renewcommand\myVersion{version 1.0\xspace}` when using this.